# webscrape script is outputting data 3 times. What did I do wrong?

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping

im trying to learn webscraping better by practicing with the basketball-reference website. I scraped what I wanted to from the website but its printing it three times when I only want it printed once. What am I doing wrong? thank you!

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

result = requests.get('https://www.basketball-reference.com/leagues/NBA_2020.html')

src = result.content

soup = bs(src, 'lxml')

teams = soup.find('div', {'class': 'overthrow table_container'})

for team in teams:
    th_tag = teams.find_all('th')
    for team in th_tag:
        print(team.text)
```

Comment: I would recommend reading the following article: https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

watch over here, you are doing this.

```
    th_tag = teams.find_all('th')
    for team in th_tag:
        print(team.text)
```

and this is printing all the text in `th` tag one by one